# How to init/set value in a superclass constructor? in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, object

#### Given these two classes:

**User**

```
    export class User {

        constructor(id?: string, userName?: string, fullName?: string,
 email?: string, jobTitle?: string, phoneNumber?: string, roles?: string[]) {
            this.id = id;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.email = email;
            this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.roles = roles;
        }

    }
```

and **UserEdit** that **extends** from **User**

```
import { User } from './user.model';


export class UserEdit extends User {
    constructor(currentPassword?: string, newPassword?: string, confirmPassword?: string) {
        super();

        this.currentPassword = currentPassword;
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public currentPassword: string;
    public newPassword: string;
    public confirmPassword: string;

}
```

It's possible from **UserEdit** set an `email` to an empty string '', from the creation of the new object?. For example.

```
let userEdit:UserEdit = new UserEdit()
```

Comment: Why use classes over interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass  parameters inside your base class by using `super(param1, param2, param3, ...)`

in your case

```
super(id, userName, fullName, email, jobTitle, phoneNumber, roles);

super(id, username, fullname, '', jobTitle, phoneNumber, roles);
```

Comment: what i want is to create an object `new UserEdit()` and from it, set the email to empty string ''.

Comment: okay, use super to set or unset them. my answer is relevant to what you need. check the usage of super. super initializes base constructor. so you need to call it like above

Comment: plus, your `User` class doesn't have any benefit of being a class instead of an interface. If it were an interface, you could just have UserEdit implement it (or `Partial<User>` for optional fields) and then interact with the fields normally.

Comment: yeah, but i inherit the project. So as the beatles said, if it works, let it be.

Comment: If you don't know what you are doing you can only sing for someone else. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simonare, also i found another solution which is elegant aswell, **function composition**.

Like this.

```
public user: User = new User('', '', '', '', '', '', ['']);
public userEdit: editUser = new UserEdit('', '', '');
public edit = () => { ...this.user, ...this.userEdit };
```